# Selecting or Ordering from Generic List with multiple purposes objects C#

Tags: c#, list, generics, select

I'm trying to create a reusable method like this

```
    public static void Order<T> (List<T> filteredList, List<T> fullList)
    {
        //Getting list of ID from all business entities.
        HashSet<long> ids = new HashSet<long>(filteredList.Select(x => x.ID));
        //Ordering the list
        return fullList.OrderByDescending(x => ids.Contains(x.ID)).ThenBy(x => !ids.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
    }
```

because I have multiple objects that do the same thing but they are differents collections types. But obviously the problem is on x.ID because ID is a property from the business entity. I mean. Imagine that T is Person and ID is the property. But ID is not recognized from a generic list and I want to do it generic because all my business entities have ID (Person, Employee, etc).

Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

L.I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an **Interface**, in this example `IBusinessEntity`, that states the item must have an ID like this:

```
public interface IBusinessEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

So, your `Person` and `Employee` classes would then change to:

```
public class Person : IBusinessEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class Employee : IBusinessEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

and then you would only allow Business Entities (in this example `Person` and `Employee`) to be passed in like so:

```
public static void Order<IBusinessEntity> (List<IBusinessEntity> filteredList, List<IBusinessEntity> fullList)
{
    //Getting list of ID from all business entities.
    HashSet<long> ids = new HashSet<long>(filteredList.Select(x => x.ID));
    //Ordering the list
    return fullList.OrderByDescending(x => ids.Contains(x.ID)).ThenBy(x => !ids.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
}
```

This of course would also allow you to create Mock `IBusinessEntity` and Unit Test this method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick answer. I'd really appreciate it. Well I saw your code and I think is terrific! I did a little app to test it and it has some changes because an interface does not allow me to define public the property and the type in Order shows me a conflict of type IBusinessEntity so I declared it Order T besides that, it's great. Finally this is the last result.

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int id { get; set; }
}

public class Person: IEntity
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : IEntity
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}

    public static List<IEntity> Order<T>(List<IEntity> filtered, List<IEntity> full)
    {
        HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>(filtered.Select(x => x.id));
        return full.OrderByDescending(x => ids.Contains(x.id)).ThenBy(x => !ids.Contains(x.id)).ToList();
    }
```

Thank you.

L.I.

Comment: Checking an answer as correct or not is down to you. What people tend to do is if the answer does indeed answer the question but then you find other issues is to mark the answer as correct and then ask another question elaborating on the next issue. Just my opinion of course! So, you may want to mark mine as answer (if you feel it does answer your question) and then post another, new, question that explains what you have above. The benefit of that is that then your new question will appear in the **"New"** list whereas re-posting here no-one will know about it or be able to help.